# Increase a UIView's width through a horizontal scrolling action?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiscrollview

Just curious if there is anyone who does have a tutorial or just an idea that supports my question above. You can think of it this way, when you horizontally increase the window size of your web browser in a desktop.

And most importantly, if Apple approves this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIScrollView` instead of `UIView`. And you can set `ScrollView's` `Content Size` ..

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 400.0)];
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
//Set its contentSize According to you
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640.0, 400.0)];
```